# How to serve docker-compose app (react-flask) using Kong?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, kong

Reverse Proxy/API Gateway noob here. 
I have a docker-compose application combining ReactJS, Flask, and MongoDB.

```
├── Makefile
├── docker-compose-dev.yml
├── docker-compose-prod.yml
└── services
    ├── flask_server
    ├── react_ui
    ├── nginx
    └── swagger
```

I used Nginx as a reverse proxy for deployment and it works well.

But I came across Kong API Gateway Service and it looks great because of the plugins and integrations. So I wanted to understand does Nginx and Kong work together or I can completely replace Nginx with Kong. If yes then how ?

Thanks

Comment: Also, I would like to understand how can I serve my react frontend through kong since it can also be considered a service itself